# Component won't update in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar, pinia

I'm using pinia to store data in my Vue app. There is a component called ListTag:

```
<template>
  <div
    v-for="(tag, index) in visibleTagItems"
    :key="index"
    class="q-mx-none q-px-none"
  >
    <q-chip
      :removable="tagsWantToggle"
      size="8px"
      outline
      :color="tag.color"
      :class="`co-${tag.color}1 text-${tag.color}  `"
      class="q-ma-none q-mr-sm"
      @remove="removeTag(index)"
    >
      {{ wantCircle(index, tag.label) }}
      <q-tooltip :class="`bg-${tag.color}`" :delay="1000" :offset="[0, 10]"
        >{{ tag.label }}
      </q-tooltip>
    </q-chip>

    <q-btn-dropdown
      v-if="tagsWantToggle && index == tagItems.length - 1 && wantDropdown"
      flat
      color="grey"
      class="q-mx-none q-px-none"
      label=""
      dropdown-icon="expand_more"
      size="8px"
    >
      <q-list
        v-for="(tagDefault, index) in dropdownTagItems"
        :key="index"
        :class="`text-${tagDefault.color}`"
      >
        <q-item clickable v-close-popup @click="addTag(tagDefault)">
          <q-item-section>
            <q-item-label>{{ tagDefault.label }} </q-item-label>
          </q-item-section>
        </q-item>
      </q-list>
    </q-btn-dropdown>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { useCounterStore } from "../../stores/database";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "list-tags",
  props: {
    tagsWantToggle: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    tagItems: {},
  },
  setup(props) {
    const store = useCounterStore();

    var wantDropdown = ref(props.tagsWantToggle);

    const visibleTagItems = ref(props.tagItems);

    const storeTagItems = store.tags;

    var dropdownTagItems = null;
    if (store.selectedEmail.tagItems) {
      dropdownTagItems = storeTagItems.filter(
        ({ label: id1 }) =>
          !store.selectedEmail.tagItems.some(({ label: id2 }) => id2 === id1)
      );
    }
    return {
      dropdownTagItems,
      storeTagItems,
      wantDropdown,
      visibleTagItems,
    };
  },
  methods: {
   ...
  },
});
</script>

<style></style>
```

The parent component called `Content` contains this code:

```
<ListTags class="row" :tagsWantToggle="true" :tagItems="store.selectedEmail.tagItems" />
```

When the page is loaded, the `selectedEmail` is just an empty object. Later, as I open one email the selected email will be filled with some data, but the `ListTags` will not be visible. It is strange, because in the `Content` file I'm using this code: `<div class="text-subtitle2">{{ store.selectedEmail.message }}</div>` and it works perfectly. It updates if another email is selected.

How could I update the tags inside `ListTag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code inside `setup` function:

```js
  const storeTagItems = store.tags;
  var dropdownTagItems = null;
  if (store.selectedEmail.tagItems) {
    dropdownTagItems = storeTagItems.filter(
      ({ label: id1 }) =>
        !store.selectedEmail.tagItems.some(({ label: id2 }) => id2 === id1)
    );
  }
```

... only runs once: when the `setup()` function is run. It doesn't run every time `store.selectedEmail.tagItems` or `store.tags` change. In other words, it's not *"reactive"*.

To make it reactive, write a computed:

```js
const dropdownTagItems = computed(() =>
  store.tags.filter(
    ({ label }) =>
      !store.selectedEmail.tagItems.some(({ label: l }) => label === l)
  )
);
```

- if `store.tags` is nullable, replace `store.tags.filter` with `(store.tags || []).filter`.
- if `store.selectedEmail` or its `tagItems` are nullable, replace `store.selectedEmail.tagItems.some` with
  `(store.selectedEmail?.tagItems || []).some`

`dropdownTagItems` will now react to any change in `store.tags` or `store.selectedEmail.tagItems`. It's reactive.

**Notes:**

- if you use `dropdownTagItems` in more than one place, consider writing a store getter and move the above computed in that getter, so you don't need to repeat yourself in multiple components.
- if you use `storeTagItems` anywhere else in the component, you should make it reactive with any of these methods:
  ***a)*** use `store.tags` directly;
  ***b)*** make it a `computed`: `const storeTagItems = computed(() => store.tags)`
  ***c)*** use the `storeToRefs` helper importable from `pinia`:
  `const { tags: storeTagItems } = storeToRefs(store)`

Answer (score 1):

These are notes from Pinia team:

- Store is an object wrapped with reactive, meaning there is no need to write .value after getters but, like props in setup, we cannot destructure it
- In order to extract properties from the store while keeping its reactivity, you need to use storeToRefs()

.

So, in your case, components are not updated because `storeTagItems` is not reactive. To make it reactive, simply destructure store with storeToRefs().

```
const {tags: storeTagItems} = storeToRefs(store))
```